# React Custom Hook Triggers Evry Where

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I Made A React Hook That Gets An Image File From File Input And Convert It Into Base64 Image Then Return It As A Callback I Use The Hook In Two Components (Avatar,Cover) In The Same Page When I Use The Hook And Select The Image  Both Of The Components callback Triggered

A Demo Of What Happening
[I Selected The Image In Avatar Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVKep.png)
[But It Renders On Both Components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdBKC.png)

The Hook

```
export const useBase64 = (
    triggerRef: HTMLButtonElement | null,
    fn?: (base64Image: string) => void
) => {
    const file = useAppSelector((state) => state.file.file);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!triggerRef) return;
        const handleClick = () => {
            document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>("#FILE")?.click();
        };
        triggerRef.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
        if (!file) return;
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = () => {
            if (fn) {
                console.log(fn);
                console.log(triggerRef);
                fn(reader.result as string);
            }
        };
        return () => {
            triggerRef.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
        };
    }, [triggerRef, file]);
};
```

The Avatar Component

```
export const Avatar: React.FC = () => {
    const avatar = useAppSelector((state) => state.user.user?.avatar);
    const avatarPreview = useAppSelector((state) => state.image.avatar);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const buttonRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);
    useBase64(buttonRef.current, (image) => {
        console.log("avatar triggerd");
        dispatch(openImage({ image, type: "avatar" }));
    });
    return (
        <button
            ref={buttonRef}
            className="avatar -translate-y-1/2 ml-6 focus:scale-[0.98] active:scale-[0.98] transition-all relative group"
        >
            <div className="absolute !flex items-center justify-center w-full h-full bg-base-300/75 z-50 rounded-full opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100 transition-all">
                <BiSolidCamera className="text-4xl" />
            </div>
            <div className="w-32 h-32 ring-8 ring-base-200 rounded-full bg-base-200 relative">
                <Image
                    width={150}
                    height={150}
                    src={avatarPreview || avatar!}
                    alt="avatar"
                    className="object-contain"
                />
            </div>
        </button>
    );
};
```

The Cover Component

```
export const Cover: React.FC<Props> = ({}) => {
    const preview = useAppSelector((state) => state.image.cover);
    const profile = useAppSelector((state) => state.user.profile) as Profile;
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
    const buttonRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);
    const cover = useBase64(buttonRef.current, (image) => {
        console.log("cover triggerd");
        dispatch(openImage({ image, type: "cover" }));
    });
    return (
        <button
            ref={buttonRef}
            className="cursor-pointer shadow-2xl btn btn-ghost rounded-none w-full block h-auto p-0 relative"
        >
            {preview || profile.cover ? (
                <Image
                    alt="cover"
                    width={1920}
                    height={1080}
                    src={preview || profile.cover!}
                    className="aspect-[16/6] active:scale-[0.98] focus:scale-[0.98] transition-all"
                />
            ) : (
                <div className="bg-base-100 aspect-[16/6] cursor-pointer flex items-center justify-center text-xl font-semibold gap-2 text-base-content/50 hover:bg-base-100/75 transition-all select-none focus:scale-[0.98] active:scale-[0.98]">
                    Upload A Cover
                    <ImUpload className="text-2xl text-secondary" />
                </div>
            )}
        </button>
    );
};
```

Comment: Looks like you add two event listeners by two hooks, which refers to same id `#FILE` inside: `const handleClick = () => { document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>("#FILE")?.click();}`. I guess it causes two clicks.

Comment: @Bartłomiej Stasiak I Tried It Cause One Click But The Cover And Avatar Callbacks both ran in the fn() part

Comment: I noticed that you have `file` in `[triggerRef, file]` and `file` is `useAppSelector(...)`. Looks like `file` is same shared state between `Avatar` and `Cover`. Change in `file` triggers your effect many times inside `useBase64(...)` - both `Avatar` and `Cover` are being rerendered.

Comment: Do You Have Any Suggestions For Solving The Problem I Can't Find Any Solution I'm Trying For A While

Comment: I Think That I Can't Make One File Input Handling All The Files

Comment: Did you try to remove `file` from `[triggerRef, file]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM I Solved It

```
export const useBase64 = (
    triggerRef: HTMLButtonElement | null,
    fn?: (base64Image: string) => void
) => {
    const id = useId();
    const inputElement: React.MutableRefObject<null | HTMLInputElement> =
        useRef(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        const input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "file";
        inputElement.current = input;
    }, [id]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const input = inputElement.current;
        if (!triggerRef || !input) return;
        const handleClick = () => {
            input.click();
        };
        triggerRef.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
        input.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
            const file = ((e.target as HTMLInputElement).files || [])[0];
            if (!file) return;
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload = () => {
                if (fn) fn(reader.result as string);
            };
        });
        return () => {
            triggerRef.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
            input.remove();
        };
    }, [triggerRef, id, inputElement]);
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).